# SyntaxError from Python Label Expression in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, python-parser, syntaxerror

I am trying to use a find label expression that changes the font of one field, `[NUMBERNAME]`. I am using the Python parser of ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop.

All fields have a data type of text. This is what I have...

```
def FindLabel ([NUMBERNAME]):
    lineone = "A:"+ [NUMBER]
    absName = "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '14'>" + [NUMBERNAME] + "</FNT></CLR>"
    if [NUMBERNAME] != None:
        return lineone + '\n' + absName + '\n' + "BLK:" + [BLOCK] + '\n' + "SEC:"+ [SURNUM]
```

I am getting an error. Any thoughts as to what is wrong?

Error:

> The expression contains an error. Modify the expression and try
>   again. Error 0 on line 0. SyntaxError: invalid syntax(string, line
>   2).

[image]

Comment: Paste here this error.

Comment: You might find it simpler to use `.format()` : `"{0}\n{1}\nBLK:{2}\nSEC:{3}".format(absName, [BLOCK], [SURNUM])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You currently have:

`lineone = "A:" + [NUMBER]` but `[NUMBER]` isn't defined anywhere.

Any fields that you want to use in the expression, you need to include as a parameter to the function.

So, it looks like you would want:

```
def FindLabel ([NUMBERNAME], [NUMBER], [BLOCK], [SURNUM]):
   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow for [NUMBER], [BLOCK], and [SURNUM] in your function.

```
def FindLabel([NUMBERNAME],[NUMBER],[BLOCK],[SURNUM]):
```

And make sure to account for `None` to be returned if any of those fields could be empty.